# UIToolbar UILabel x y offset not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I encountered a strange problem. I need to put two UILabel in UIToolbar. I have a button and I want to share with respect to its center the UILabel, as if I did not change the values of x and y inside UILabel up at the bottom, they do not move. Tell me what could be the problem. I need a little lower down the UILabel.

```
= [NSMutableArray new];
_createdLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
_createdLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_createdLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamPro-Light" size:15.0f ];
_createdLabel.font = myFont;
_createdLabel.text = @"";
UIBarButtonItem *createdTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_createdLabel];
[_items addObject:createdTitle];

UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[_items addObject:space];

UILabel *shareLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, -1000, 85, 20)];
shareLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
shareLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIFont *shareFont = [ UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamPro-Light" size:15.0f ];
shareLabel.font = shareFont;
shareLabel.text = @"Поделиться";
[shareLabel sizeToFit];
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(socialSharing:)];
[shareLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[shareLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
UIBarButtonItem *shareTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:shareLabel] ;
[_items addObject:shareTitle];

UIBarButtonItem *shareBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(socialSharing:)];
shareBtn.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[_items addObject:shareBtn];
[self.toolBar setItems:_items animated:YES];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please remove [shareLabel sizeToFit]; in your code.

Use below code for share label.

```
    UILabel *shareLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 4, 85, 16)];
```

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work, the text is exactly UIToolbar center. Previously, I had a different font, fatter, it was great, I think it's just UIToolbar does not allow me to move down the top of the UILabel.

Comment: Not like that, we can move it.

Comment: Can you give me your custom toolbar x, y , width, height?

Comment: My UIToolbar inside storyboard, 0 534 320 44

Comment: Are you create your own UIToolbar?

    - (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 5, 0, 5};
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
    }

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[_items addObject:space];


I thought, you added space making issues. **Try to remove that**.

Answer (score 0):

You try this code, it's working fine

```
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
    [toolBar setBarTintColor: self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor];
    NSMutableArray *items= [NSMutableArray new];
    UILabel *createdLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)];
    createdLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    createdLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamPro-Light" size:15.0f ];
    createdLabel.font = myFont;
    createdLabel.text = @"Hai";
    UIBarButtonItem *createdTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:createdLabel];
    [items addObject:createdTitle];

    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:space];

    UILabel *shareLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 85, 20)];
    shareLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    shareLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIFont *shareFont = [ UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamPro-Light" size:15.0f ];
    shareLabel.font = shareFont;
    shareLabel.text = @"Hello  "; //@"Поделиться";
    [shareLabel sizeToFit];
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(socialSharing)];
    [shareLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [shareLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    UIBarButtonItem *shareTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:shareLabel] ;
    [items addObject:shareTitle];

    UIBarButtonItem *shareBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(socialSharing)];
    shareBtn.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [items addObject:shareBtn];
    [toolBar setItems:items animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

provide method like this,

```
-(void)socialSharing
{
    NSLog(@"Hai");
}
```

Definitely helps to you.